# Is there an alternative to union all that can stack data on top of each other?

Tags: sql

I need to create a view that stacks various possible cuts of data on top of each other.  In my example, I have the fields id, location, and sub_location.  I need every possible combination of the data as shown below.  So far, I've been doing this using union all, but in reality I have about 15 different fields that I need to cut by and using union all for this is causing what is a relatively basic query to become very large and error-prone.

```
    select a.id, a.location, a.sub_location
    from a
union all
    select 'All' id, a.location, a.sub_location
    from a
union all
    select 'All' id, 'All' location, a.sub_location
    from a
union all
    select 'All' id, 'All' location, 'All' sub_location
    from a
union all
    select 'All' id, a.location, 'All' sub_location
    from a
union all
    select a.id, 'All' location, 'All' sub_location
    from a
union all
    select a.id, 'All' location, a.sub_location
    from a
union all
    select a.id, a.location, 'All' sub_location
    from a;
```

Any suggestions for a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: why do it in sql? you're just producing useless extra records - why not do this in client-side code? fetch a single record, then you duplicate it into `(id/loc/sub)`, `(all/loc/sub)`, `(id/all/sub)`, etc... tuples.

Comment: You are duplicating your table multiple times in this way. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The end goal of this is to be able to provide survey results by a variety of cuts, but the results are calculated in an odd way.  The average response for each question gets rounded to the nearest whole percentage, and then the questions are grouped (e.g. group 1 score = average(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4), where Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4 are the rounded averages for those questions for the cut of interest).  If there were no pre-rounding, this would be very straight-forward view to create.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  You could do what you are doing using `cross join`:

```
select coalesce(tid.id, a.id) as id,
       coalesce(tloc.location, a.location) as location,
       coalesce(tloc.sub_location, a.sub_location) as sub_location
from a cross join
     (select 'ALL' as id union all NULL end) tid cross join
     (select 'ALL' as location union all NULL end) tloc cross join
     (select 'ALL' as sub_location union all NULL end) tsubloc ;
```